# How to use ng-repeat to iterate over map entries in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How would you iterate over the entries in map such that both the entry key and the value can be printed? For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat='mapEntry in {"First Name":"John", "Last Name":"Smith"}'>
        <span>Key: {{mapEntry.key}}, value: {{mapEntry.value}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If looking to iterate through an actual `Map`, this questions covers it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44073208/how-to-iterate-through-javascript-maps-using-ng-repeat-in-angularjs

Answer (score 152, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#ngRepeat-arguments), I found this syntax works:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat='(key, value) in {"First Name":"John", "Last Name":"Smith"}'>
        <span>Key: {{key}}, value: {{value}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```