# Remove element from javascript object in angular repeat loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have data in the following form:

```
$scope.cart={"4": {"cost": 802.85,  "description": "test", "qty": 1},
"5": {"cost": 802.85,  "description": "test", "qty": 1}};
```

I'd like to loop through this data and display it alongside remove button. How can I make the button remove the row from the scope and also trigger angular digest? All of the tutorials seem to have the data in array, and splicing that array, this does not fit my needs.

This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/wbebc4cd/1/

Comment: So what is the problem, seems to work?

Comment: Sorry, bad link. I've updated the question.

Comment: First of all the demo doesn't run. I also recommend to use Angular 1.3.x.

Comment: I know that it does not run. But why?

Comment: Because you forgot a comma after function expression. http://jsfiddle.net/wbebc4cd/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @dfsq mentioned, you have a typo in your function.

But more fundamentally, when repeating over the map, you should also remember the key. (See also [How to use ng-repeat to iterate over map entries in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704147/how-to-use-ng-repeat-to-iterate-over-map-entries-in-angularjs))

```
<tr ng:repeat="(key,item) in cart">
```

Then you can use the key to remove the item.

```
<td>[<a href ng:click="removeItem(key)">X</a>]</td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wbebc4cd/5/

Comment: You help me out of large problem !

Answer (score 1):

here is the correct code for getting the item removed.

```
function CartForm($scope) {
    $scope.cart=[{"id": 1, "cost": 802.85,  "description": "test", "qty": 1}, {"id": 2, "cost": 802.85,  "description": "test", "qty": 1}];


    $scope.removeItem = function(item) {
        var index = $scope.cart.indexOf(item);
        $scope.cart.splice(index, 1);

    }


}
```

Comment: Yes, you can look up the value in the map. But I think it's clearer to store the key when iterating.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
$scope.removeItem = function(item) { 
    var newCart = {};
    angular.forEach($scope.cart, function(value, key){
        if(value != item)
            newCart[key] = value; 
    });

    $scope.cart = newCart;   
};
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0v40rhfb/2/