# How can I iterate over multiple maps (key,value) using ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my controller, I have data like this:

```
"type":       [
              {
        "aMap": {"5.0": 0},
        "bMap": {"10.0": 0},
        "cMap": {"15.0": 0},
        "dMap": {"20.0": 0},
        "desc": "CG"
},
{
        "aMap": {"5.0": 0},
        "bMap": {"10.0": 0},
        "cMap": {"15.0": 0},
        "dMap": {"20.0": 0},
        "desc": "CG"
}]
```

It contains arrays which has multiple maps. I want to read both key, value in the maps in my html using ng-repeat. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704147/how-to-use-ng-repeat-to-iterate-over-map-entries-in-angularjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ng-repeat to iterate over map entries in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704147/how-to-use-ng-repeat-to-iterate-over-map-entries-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you can loop using:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in type">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">
      <b>KEY</b> : {{key}}
      <b>ITEM</b> : {{val}}
      <br/>
      <i>KEY / VAL of data :</i>
      <div ng-repeat="(keylower, vallower) in val">
        {{keylower}} - {{vallower}}
      </div>
      <br/><br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

See this code example on Plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/nXEwJ5IcD4Cu8wrFjR2R?p=preview

Comment: Here Item is still an array. How do I read the (key,value) in that as well?

Comment: Thank you so much @daan.desmedt :)

Comment: Do you have any idea how will I display it in a table?

Comment: If it answers your question, please accept this as the answer. How do you want the table to look like?

Comment: It should be like:

<tr>
<td>desc</td> 
<td>aMapKey</td> 
<td>aMapValue</td> 
<td>bMapKey</td> 
<td>bMapValue</td> 
<td>cMapKey</td> 
<td>cMapValue</td> 
<td>dMapKey <t/d>
<td>dMapValue</td>
</tr>

Comment: You can wrap the repeaters in the mentioned table structure. Just replace the `<div>` with the matching table elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="foo in data">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in foo">
```